# How to bind JavaScript event in Angular2? (jQuery datatable + Angular2)

Tags: jquery, angular, datatable

[For pagination and sorting jQuery data table is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaHJf.png)

I added button next to filter by using

```
$("#example").DataTable({
  "ajax": "http://localhost:8090/all",
  "columns": [
    {"data": "name"},
    {"data": "email"},
    {"data": "qualification"},
    {"data": "designation"}
  ],
  "sAjaxDataProp": "",
  dom: 'l<"toolbar">frtip',
  initComplete: function () {
     $("div.dataTables_filter").append(_this.str);
  }
})
```

it created button but (click) event is not binding. Here is the full code snippet

```
 import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
 import {Contact} from "./contact";
 import {ContactService} from "./contact.service";

  declare  var $:any;

  @Component({
      selector: 'app-contact',
      templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
  })
  export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

       contacts : Contact[]=[];
       flag : any;

      str=' <button type="button" id="any_button" 
      class="btn-primary" (click)="hllo()"> Add Employee</button>';
    constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {
    }

   hello(){
      alert("Do something");
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  var _this=this;
   $("#example").DataTable({
        "ajax": "http://localhost:8090/all",
         "columns": [
         {"data": "name"},
         {"data": "email"},
         {"data": "qualification"},
         {"data": "designation"}
         ],
         "sAjaxDataProp": "",
         dom: 'l<"toolbar">frtip',
         initComplete: function () {
             $("div.dataTables_filter").append(_this.str);
          }
    })

   }
 }
```

Here something is fundamentally wrong, can some please help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not (under common usage cases) mix jquery and angular2, it is better to define elements in dom, but hide them with *ngIf... and bind all necessary properties.

UPDATE: A little bit of workaround, but could help you. I had to adapt a huge project of old (partially pre-jquery) code to angular2. It was a tree like component structure (even at that time). Now it is mixture of two approaches old_code/angular2. And You can make the code following:

```
declare let window;
...
constructor() { window["my_unique_class_name"]=this;}
...
 str=' <button type="button" id="any_button" 
      class="btn-primary" onclick="my_unique_class_name.hello()"> Add Employee</button>';

...
 initComplete: () => {
             $("div.dataTables_filter").append(this.str);
          }
```

Comment: initComplete: function () {
             $("div.dataTables_filter").append(_this.str);
  }  I found only the way to added button to the jQuery datatable. *ngIf i couldn't use.

Comment: It worked, but I din't not following the code. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any kind of Angular binding or component/directive selectors in dynamically added HTML, they **only** work when added statically to a components template.

What you can do is adding it imperatively by injecting `ElementRef`, querying for the element and add an event handler using `addEventHandler` or some similar jQuery method if you are already using it anyway:

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  var _this=this;
   $("#example").DataTable({
        "ajax": "http://localhost:8090/all",
         "columns": [
         {"data": "name"},
         {"data": "email"},
         {"data": "qualification"},
         {"data": "designation"}
         ],
         "sAjaxDataProp": "",
         dom: 'l<"toolbar">frtip',
         initComplete: function () {
             $("div.dataTables_filter").append(_this.str);
             _this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div.dataTables_filter > button').addEventHandler('click', _this.hello);
             // or just plain jQuery
             $("div.dataTables_filter > button").click(_this.hello);
          }
    })

 }
```

Comment: The following error message: inline template:33:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'addEventHandler' of null

Comment: Sorry, the code should be inside the `initComplete` callback - updated my answer.

Comment: Eror message :  Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: I don't know when `initComplete` gets called. You could try to change `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Sorry, still same problem persists : Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: Should be `_this.elRef` instead of `this.elRef`. If you are using `(params) => { ... }` (arrow function) instead of `function (params) { ... }` consistently, then you don't need to use `var _this = this;` because `this.` will then always point to the current class.